# githubでforkしたgo言語のリポジトリのimport文がずれる

Tags: git, go, github

githubでgo言語で書かれたリポジトリをforkして作業するときに、import文がずれるのはどうやって解消するのがいいのでしょうか？

例えば、hogeさんのfoobarリポジトリからforkしてくると、

```
import "github.com/hoge/foobar/client"
```

のようにインポートされています。

hogeの部分を自分のユーザ名に書き換えても、pull requestを送るときに戻すのがめんどくさいですし、そもそもちゃんと管理できません。。。

Comment: なぜずれると困るのかといった情報を載せておくと、回答者の参考になると思います。あと、どうなっておいて欲しいのかも書いておくと良いと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こちらの方法が良いと思います:
[GithubのGo言語プロジェクトにPull Requestを送るときのimport問題 | SOTA](http://deeeet.com/writing/2014/07/23/golang-pull-request/)

Answer (score 9):

手順を書いときます。

1. オリジナルをGOPATH上の正しい場所に clone する 
   `git clone git@github.com:wizard/awesome.git`
2. github で fork する
3. オリジナルと同じワーキングディレクトリの remote に fork を追加する
   `git remote add mine git@github.com:myname/awesome.git`
4. 作業ブランチを作って修正を行う `git checkout -b newfeature`
5. 自分のレポジトリに push する `git push -u mine newfeature`
6. pull request を作る

GOPATH上でのディレクトリレイアウトを、オリジナルレポジトリに合わせしまうのです。

Comment: 1. で、GOPATH内のパスを指定してcloneする必要があるのでは? (そしてforkしてからcloneしてもok。clone先のパスを指定するので、clone元がどういう名前でも大丈夫なため)

Comment: あ、もちろんcloneするのは、GOPATH上で正しい場所ですね。(書くまでもないことだと考えてましたw)

Comment: 確認ありがとうございます! 文字通りにうけとってしまいがちなもので.. いち読者としてはコピペビリティが高いとうれしいです (mattnさんの回答のような感じ)

Answer (score 7):

対象のリポジトリが対象ユーザの import 構成になっているので、自分のリポジトリ内で作業するともちろん正しくビルド出来ません。
PR を送る目的ならば import 等は書き換えず対象ユーザのリポジトリ内で作業すべきかと思います。

例えば hoge さんが foo さんのリポジトリ bar に対して PR を送る場合、GOPATH 内で foo/bar を git clone します。

```
mkdir -p /path/to/GOPATH/src/github.com/foo
cd /path/to/GOPATH/src/github.com/foo
git clone https://github.com/foo/bar
cd bar
```

PR 用のブランチを作成

```
git checkout -b feature-branch
vim kanari-sugoi.go
git commit -a -m "Super awesome changes"
```

hub コマンド等で fork

```
hub fork
git push hoge feature-branch
```

自分のリポジトリに foo/bar を push します。

後は github.com/foo/bar を見に行けば pull-request ボタンが押せる様になっているはずです。